# Losing precision (using GMP) when calculating pi with sequential bbp

Tags: c, precision, gmp, sequential, pi

I'm trying to implement [this](http://en.literateprograms.org/Pi_with_the_BBP_formula_%28Python%29#Sequential_generation) algorithm in C (instead of Python) using GMP. Their Python code is quite short; however, the C implementation is a lot longer because we can't do the casting GMPY supports.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

void f_mod(mpq_t input) {
    mpf_t numerator;
    mpf_init(numerator);
    mpf_set_z(numerator, mpq_numref(input));
    mpf_t denominator;
    mpf_init(denominator);
    mpf_set_z(denominator, mpq_denref(input));
    mpf_t div;
    mpf_init(div);
    mpf_t integer_part;
    mpf_init(integer_part);

    // Integer component
    mpq_t floored;
    mpq_init(floored);

    mpf_div(div, numerator, denominator);
    mpf_floor(integer_part, div);
    mpq_set_f(floored, integer_part);

    // Get fractional part
    mpq_sub(input, input, floored);
}

int main() {

    unsigned long end_val = 1000;

    mpq_t x;
    mpq_init(x);
    mpq_set_ui(x, 0, 1);

    mpq_t p;
    mpq_init(p);

    mpq_t res;
    mpq_init(res);

    mpq_t sixteen;
    mpq_init(sixteen);
    mpq_set_ui(sixteen, 16, 1);

    unsigned long n = 1;

    printf("\n");

    short* results = (short*) malloc(end_val * sizeof(short));

    while (n < end_val)
    {
        mpq_set_ui(p, (120*n-89)*n+16, (((512*n-1024)*n+712)*n-206)*n+21);

        mpq_mul(res, x, sixteen);

        mpq_add(res, res, p);

        f_mod(res);

        mpq_set(x, res);

        mpq_mul(res, res, sixteen);

        results[n] = (short) mpq_get_d(res);

        n++;
    }

    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
    for (unsigned long a = 0; a < end_val; a++)
    {
        snprintf(buffer, 16, "%x", results[a]);
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output becomes incorrect after 3.243F6A8885A308D313198A.... What's happening?

EDIT: I changed the f_mod() method so it subtracts two mpqs instead of mpfs. This increased accuracy a little bit, but still not enough.

EDIT 2: I tried running this program on my other PC, and it magically worked! Not sure what's different other than the fact the laptop I wrote this on was 32-bit and the desktop on which it worked was 64-bit. It also might be a bug in the GMP implementation (version packaged into Debian Wheezy). However, I do suspect there is something wrong with that sequential BBP formula. I think I'll try to re-derive it.

Comment: `(char*) malloc(sizeof(char))` == `malloc(1)`.  `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1` and you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` in C.

Comment: Do you really need to use an `mpf_t` to compute the fractional part of an `mpq_t`? By the way, this kind of program is so much more readable in C++ using gmpxx.h...

Comment: @Marc Glisse No, I don't really need to, the original version of this code would basically get the double form of the mpq_t and cast it to an integer. Then it would convert that integer into an mpq_t and subtract it from the original mpq_t. But since it was losing precision I decided to avoid types which had any chance of decreasing the precision. The old version probably works now and most likely is faster.

Comment: @AnimatedRNG I mean that going through a floating point type, be it double or mpf_t, is wrong. You can go straight from mpq_t to mpz_t.

Comment: @MarcGlisse How? I can't find a conversion from mpq_t to mpz_t (which would leave only an integer part) in the GMP manual. Perhaps you mean avoiding mpf_t by dividing the numerator by the denominator using mpz_ts and subtracting that from the original mpq_t (with the fractional part)?

Comment: `mpz_set_q`. You can see its one line inline implementation in gmp.h, which matches the end of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here looks like a likely culprit:

```
char* buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Here you allocate space for only a *single* character.

Comment: That's a mistake, but not one that's causing the problem. It should just be one char (don't know why I made an array of 1). Plus, it shouldn't matter, each iteration only gets one digit. One char should be sufficient.

Comment: When n = 24, res starts to look different from the values in the python program. Not sure what causes this.

Comment: @AnimatedRNG If it's supposed to be just a single-char buffer, why are you then using this buffer to store up to 16 characters? Even if it's just a single digit in the string, you have to remember that in C strings always have an extra terminator character, so your `snprintf` call in the loop will store at least *two* characters in this buffer. This leads to buffer overflow and  *undefined behavior*, meaning the result will always be suspicious.

Comment: I see what you're saying now (the second argument of snprintf is wrong). Yeah, that's a problem, although I fixed it on the problematic computer and the result was no different. Thanks for mentioning it though.